# $J/I\trianglelefteq R/J$ Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, equivalence-relations, quotient-group

Let $R$ be a ring and $I,J\trianglelefteq R$ and $I\subset J$. We define $f: R/I \rightarrow R/J, x\mapsto [x]$ Show that:

$J/I\trianglelefteq R/I$  where $J/I = \{[x]\in R/I: x\in J\}$

So I'm supposed to show that this is an ideal. That 0 is contained in it is clear to me, but the fact that we are in a quotient group makes it hard for me to see how to prove the other two criteria for $J/I$ being an ideal.

Comment: There isn’t anything about being a quotient that should inhibit you. Just write out what you’re trying to prove.

Comment: @Christian Singer: do you mean $J/I\trianglelefteq R/I$?

Comment: Oh yes, my bad I fixed it

Comment: What does the $f$ have to do with the question?

Comment: Well it was in the prequisites of the question but I don't think that it was for this part of the exercise (it has three parts)

Comment: I agree with @rschwieb; there is nothing particularly challenging about this exercise. Remember that an element of $R/I$ is just a coset $r + I$ for some $r \in R$, and that the addition and multiplication operations are defined via addition and multiplication on the representatives, i.e. $(r + I) + (r' + I) = (r+r') + I$ and $(r + I)(r' + I) = (rr' + I)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi:R\to R/I$ denote the canonical projection modulo $I$.
Then $\pi$ is an $R$-module homomorphism.
Moreover, $J/I$ is the image of $J$ through $\pi$ hence $J/I$ is an $R$-submodule of $R/I$.
Since $I\subseteq\operatorname{Ann}_R(J/I)$, it follows that $J/I$ is, in fact, an $R/I$-submodule of $R/I$, that's an ideal of $R/I$.